# stop loading page selenium as soon as pyqt button is clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyqt5

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://9gag.com")#page that take too much time to load
```

Since this page took too much time to load I want to stop loading that page as soon as I click a pyQt button and start filling form.I dont want to use browser.set_page_load_timeout as I dont know when to stop

```
def stop_page_load():
    global driver
    """What should be the definition so that as soon as I
       click btn4,browser should stop loading"""



###w is a QWidget
btn4=QtWidgets.QPushButton("stop page load",w)
btn4.pressed.connect(stop_page_load)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load firefox with `pageLoadStrategy` as `none`. Then you can stop the page loading, but the side effect of this is that you will need to wait for loading of page yourself at all places as selenium won't do that automatically for you. You can also use `eager` instead of `none` which would wait for readyState of page to be true, but still give you sometime for page to load

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

cap = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
cap["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
print(DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap)

driver.get("https://9gag.com")#page that take too much time to load

time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

**Edit-1: Older version of firefox**

For older version of firefox you need to set the profile preference as these browser don't use marrionette

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: That worked superb.Thanks.Could you just also tell me from where you master selenium so deeply

Comment: @palakbansal, nothing specific just reading what others share and sharing what I know

Comment: hey @TarunLalwani   this worked perfectly for me in firefox version 55 and selenium  3.4.3   but I have a constraint that at workplace I have to work in firefox 28 or firefox 32 and selenium 2.41.And your code waits until the page is load completely.I am ready to wait explicitly for element.Can u help me out :)

Comment: @palakbansal, added answer for older versions also

Comment: Thanks I will try this tomorrow :)

Comment: Hey @TarunLalwani this worked but anotherproblem occured that if I find_element page first loads and then return element so I thought of pressing escape so I used ActionChains on the driver.But ActionsChains too didn't worked :(

Comment: `driver.execute_script("window.stop();")` didn't work?

Comment: No :( it didnt worked.The problem that you solved was that my Ipython console was not hanged when  I use driver.get(" page ")